# OptaPlanner Benchmark config failing due to <solver/> element namespace mismatch

Tags: optaplanner

I'm trying to use the OptaPlanner Benchmarking module. My benchmark config file is being rejected due to the following error:

```
The <solver/> element belongs to a different namespace (https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark) than expected (https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/solver).
```

I took the basics of my config from [the example in the docs](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/benchmarking-and-tweaking/benchmarking-and-tweaking.html#buildAndRunAPlannerBenchmark) and I haven't changed any of the xsd / xsi links etc. The example shows  tags in the . My IDE doesn't give me any xml formatting errors.

I've paired the file down to just the base  section where I define the shared model classes / score definitions and it results in the same problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plannerBenchmark xmlns="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark https://www.optaplanner.org/xsd/benchmark/benchmark.xsd">
<benchmarkDirectory>benchmarks</benchmarkDirectory>
<warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>30</warmUpSecondsSpentLimit>

<inheritedSolverBenchmark>
    <solver>
        <solutionClass>my.package.SchedulingSolution</solutionClass>
        <entityClass>my.package.ISchedulable</entityClass>
        <entityClass>my.package.Booking</entityClass>
<scoreDirectorFactory><constraintProviderClass>my.package.SchedulingConstraintProvider</constraintProviderClass></scoreDirectorFactory>
    </solver>
</inheritedSolverBenchmark>
```

I'm invoking it using `var benchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromSolverConfigXmlResource("config-benchmark.xml");` in a `main` method.

Am I doing something obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are passing the `benchmark-config.xml` to the wrong method; `createFromSolverConfigXmlResource` expects a `solver-config.xml`. It creates a basic benchmark from an existing solver configuration.

In fact, the solver config is a subset of the benchmark config, but they have a separate XML namespace.

Please take a look at the method `createFromXmlResource`, which expects the `benchmark-config.xml`.

Comment: Well spotted. I hadn't noticed I was using the wrong PlannerBenchmarkFactory  method. That's sorted it!

Comment: I will look into improving the fail-fast message to make it really obvious. I bet you're not the only one who has run into this.